# Change color of links created with \in, \at, etc

Tags: cross-referencing, color, context, interaction

By default the link color of references created with `\in` or `\at` is red.

How can this color be globally changed, so that all links have the same color (e.g. blue)?

```
\setupinteraction
    [state=start,
     color=blue,
     style=,  % make font non-bold
     ]

\starttext

\placefigure[here][fig:foo]{A figure}{
    \externalfigure[testfigure]
}

Red color: \in{Figure}[fig:foo] \at{page}[fig:foo].  % How to make this blue, too?

Blue color: \goto{Link}[url(http://tex.stackexchange.com/)]

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ConTeXt distinguishes between references to the same page and to
references which destination is on other pages. References which destination is on the same page
don't obey the `color` setting. Instead the colour is controlled by
a key called `contrastcolor`, which is red by default.

To change all links to blue set `color` as well as `contrastcolor`:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   color=blue,
   contrastcolor=blue]
```

See [ConTeXt wiki - setupinteraction](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinteraction)